# How to fetch array of images from amazon s3 ? NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

This code snippet generates image url of AWS s3 by giving Image name as input.I have an array of images names to generate so now I am looping this code.But it is taking too much time to generate url, also for some images urls are mssing.Is there any alter native solution ?

```
let folder = data;
  try {
    const listPhotos = await s3.listObjects({
      Bucket: bucket_name,
      Delimiter: folder,
      Prefix: folder
    }).promise();
    if (listPhotos.Contents.length) {
      let params = {
        Bucket: bucket_name,
        Key: folder,
        Expires: 86400
      }

      let orginalImageUrl = await s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', params);
      //console.log("-----",orginalImageUrl);
      return orginalImageUrl;

    } else {
      let orginalImageUrl = "no image";
      return {ImageURL: orginalImageUrl};

    }
} catch (e) {
            return e
        }
```

Comment: If you have `baseURL` you can append the path which you will get from `listObjects` and you will get the URL don't need to call `getSignedUrl `

Comment: Thanks for responding Generated url is authenticated one and it expires in 7 hours.That is why I wanted to generate image url for every image.

Comment: let orginalImageUrl = await s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', params).promise();

Comment: Still I ll have to loop right? if I have 10 image names in an array ,I ll have to call this function 10 times to generate URL of each image.! :(